# Minimize area of a triangle

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, area

> Let $\Delta \mathrm\,{ABC}$ be a triangle in the plane and $X,\, Y,\,Z$ be points on sides $BC,\, CA,\,AB$, respectively.
>
> If lines $XY$ and $AB$ are not parallel, there is a location for $Z$ for each location of points $X$ and $Y$ so that the area of $\Delta\,XYZ$ becomes maximal.
>
> Prove that, if lines $XY$ and $AB$ are parallel, the area of $\Delta\,XYZ$ is smaller than every such possible maximum area of $\Delta\,XYZ$ for non-parallel $XY$ and $AB$.

I have already figured that, for given $X$ and $Y$, the area of $\Delta\,XYZ$ becomes maximal if $Z$ lies on that ending of segment $AB$ which has a larger distance to line $XY$ (so $Z$ is located on either point $A$ or point $B$).

Also, when $XY$ an $AB$ are parallel, there is only one possible area for $\Delta\,XYZ$ as the perpendicular height and hence the area are constant and don't depend on the location of $Z$.

But how does that help in solving the actual task?

I am grateful for any hints on this!

Comment: If $AB$ and $XY$ are parallel, then every triangle $XYZ$ with $Z$ on the line $AB$ will have the same area since the perpendicular height is the same. So the maximum and minimum areas are the same...

Comment: That's what I meant with "the exact location of $Z$ would be irrelevant...". So I think the task is to prove that this specific area, which is independent of the location of $Z$, is smaller than the respective maximum areas if $XY$ and $AB$ are not parallel.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but the statement seems wrong. If you take $X$ very close to $B$ and $Y$ very close to $A$ (but so that $XY$ is not parallel to $AB$), then the maximum area of $XYZ$ (the maximum of the areas of $XYA$ and $XYB$) can be made as close to zero as you like. All these numbers can't be larger than if you take $X, Y$ fixed so that $XY$ is parallel to $AB$.